# Install Podman on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, podman

Trying to install Podman on Ubuntu 20.04, and it turns out to be very challenging.

- [This](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-and-use-podman-on-ubuntu-22-04/) blogs says it includes installing Podman on Ubuntu 22.04 ***& 20.04***, but 20.04 is not covered, as I found no Ubuntu focal 20.04 *official packages*, not even in focal-updates or focal-backports.
- [This](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-podman-on-ubuntu) blogs does include installing Podman on 20.04, but I found it no longer working, as
- Even the official [Podman Installation Instruction](https://podman.io/docs/installation) doesn't cover Ubuntu, only Debian.

So, is it still possible to install Podman *stable* on Ubuntu 20.04? thx

Comment: A quick look and the *libc6* provided in *focal* (20.04) is too old, and upgrading that would also mean your system is no longer Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (upgrading to 22.04 being the safest option). I didn't look to see if an older podman is available that may work on *focal*.

Answer (score 2):

> - Even the official Podman Installation Instruction doesn't cover Ubuntu, only Debian.

Huh? Have a look down the [official Podman page](https://podman.io/docs/installation#ubuntu), where the following is stated in plain English:

> The podman package is available in the official repositories for Ubuntu 20.10 and newer.

Also, as you already found out, the [Kubic project](https://build.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:kubic:libcontainers:unstable/podman) no longer supports Ubuntu 20.04 either, only 22.04.

So no, Podman is not officially supported on Ubuntu 20.04. And thus getting it to work on 20.04 will require some amounts of completely unsupported and manual hacking.